# C#.Net Windows Application Hindi Writing and display

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode

I am working on a windows form application project using VS 2008 Express with C# in which both hindi and english data needs to be stored in SQL Server 2008 Express database.

I have created a table with `NVARCAR(MAX)` columns and used the following code for storing hindi into database:

```
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test(name, data) VALUES (@a, @b)";
com.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  textBox1.Text.Trim();
com.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  textBox2.Text.Trim();

con.Open();

if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Failed");

con.Close();
```

The code works perfectly fine, and saves data in hindi.

Now following is the problem I am facing:

1. When retrieving, I see question marks instead of hindi characters in datagridview and label. I need to show hindi as a result of select query. This is the code that I am using:

   ```
   com.CommandText = "SELECT data FROM test WHERE name=@name";
   com.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text.Trim();

   con.Open();

   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);

   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

   SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

   if(dr.HasRows)
   {
       while(dr.Read())
       {
           textBox2.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
       }
   }

   con.Close();
   ```

   NOTE: Hindi comparison works fine but hindi is not displayed in datagridview and label/textbox.

   NOTE: I'm using Windows 7 that may not have hindi installed. Also, I cannot install hindi regional language because it demands licensed windows and I cannot be sure that every machine will have a licensed version.
2. Also, the mentioned code works fine on copy-pasted hindi. I cannot type in hindi while inserting data.

Kindly Help.

Comment: Your issue is that the language is not installed on the machine. To the best of my knowledge there isn't a way around that. If the language is not on the machine how could you expect it to display or allow typing of that language?

Comment: Hi. I am not really sure if this is a language issue or if I have hindi installed or not. As mentioned in description, I am able to copy hindi from browser, paste it in .net textbox, save it in database and fire Select query with Where Clause on hindi text. I am able to read hindi by copy pasting. Just not able to show it in label from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem and would like to share the solution so that all visitors may know that this is the right approach and doesnot need much extra labor.

Following are the solutions:

1. For 1st problem, the code of question is the answer itself. Only the datatypes of both columns: name and data in database needs to be Nvarchar. By mistake, i kept data column as varchar and that was the actual problem.
2. To allow hindi typing, just add hindi language to the keyboard layout in regional settings and follow the answer of @cshapcoder in this post: [Hindi Input in textbox c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382803/hindi-input-in-textbox-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 1):

Although installing a font will be the only option for it, but Unicode can also be used to display data if the data is stored in hexadecimal Unicode as:

```
    void Main()
    {
       string input = "0935;093F;0928;094B;0926;";
       Regex rx = new Regex(@"([0-9A-Fa-f]{4});");
       string output = rx.Replace(input, match => ((char)Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
       textBox2.Text = output;
    }
```

The following is a one line example to use Unicode, for this to work you must change the console font to something that supports Unicode:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}","\u0935\u093F\u0928\u094B\u0926");
```

For a list of Unicode Tables find see [unicode-table.com](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0928) but [rapidtables](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html) is better for Unicode escape sequence

Comment: Hi. I think NVarChar stores Unicode data. but what is the Input string that you have written in this code? What data it is?

Comment: It's a Unicode number to represent Unicode characters http://unicode-table.com/en/#0935